# How Can Retrieving child value from root firebase url

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

How Can Access Name,Email,Contact etc. from root firebase url.
Means RootUrl --> UserDetails --> Ad --> Ad123 --> Name,Email etc.
I Used below Code But It not Retrieving data from database and toast not appearing. 
The Code Image is Attached.[Data Structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxmTz.png)
[Code for retrieving data from databse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0Pj3.png)

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("UserDetails").child("Ad").child("Ad123");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String contact = dataSnapshot.child("Contact").getValue(String.class);
        String dob = dataSnapshot.child("DOB").getValue(String.class);
        String departemnt = dataSnapshot.child("Departemnt").getValue(String.class);
        //and so on
        Log.d("TAG", contact + " / " + dob + " / " + departemnt);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to point out to a node of a Firebase. For that you could use -

```
 DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("UserDetails/Ad/Ad123");
```